# Check if a file is an SSH Private Key or a Public Key

Tags: python, ssh-keys

I've got a tool I wrote in Python, that ingests a path to a file. I want to check if it's an SSH Private key, or a public key, (disregard if neither). I'm not sure how to pragmatically check if a file is either of these. Is there a way in Python to do this?

Answer (score 3):

There are many complex forms of these keys. It will be hard to distinguish them.

There are

- public keys which consist of one line whose format differs depending on if you have RSA, DSA or Version 1 keys.
- private keys which are compatible to OpenSSH. They start with

  ```
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  ```

  and end with

  ```
  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  ```

  (provided it is an RSA key), other strings for DSA or version 1.
- SSH.COM and PuTTY have another different format.

Good luck!

Maybe you can convice `ssh-keygen` to do this job for you...